# How to find posts.map error when I think its array already

Tags: reactjs, function, next.js, typeerror

This is error I get:

```
98 | 
   99 | <section>
> 100 | {posts.map((post) =>(
      |     ^
  101 | <BlogCard title={post.title} 
  102 | author={post.author} 
  103 | coverPhoto={post.coverPhoto}
```

This is my code, I tried to find why its not array and no luck, this is my first post here so I don't know if I made it like I should. But I had no luck finding an answer..

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Navi from '/components/nav.js'
import Header from '/components/header.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request';
import BlogCard from '/components/BlogCard'

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(
  "SomeAPI"
);
const QUERY = gql`
 {
  posts {
    id
    title
    datepublish
    slug
    content{
      html
    }
    author{
      ime
      avatar{
        url
      }
    }
    coverPhoto{
      url
    }
    }
  }
`;
export async function getStaticProps(){
  const {posts} =  await graphcms.request(QUERY); 
  return{
    props:{
    posts,
  },
  revalidate:10,
};
}
export default function Home(posts) {

  return (
    <div >
      <Head>
        <title>Osnovna Skola Vuk Karadzic</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Web sajt OS Vuk Karadzic Rocevic" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/Logo,_Os_Vuk_Karadzic_Rocevic.png" />
      </Head>

      <main >
    <section>
      <Header />
    </section>


<section>
  <nav>
    <Navi />
    </nav>
    <div>
    <img className='relative  -z-10  ' src="naslovnaslika.jpg" alt="slika skolske torbe na stolu" />
  </div>
  
       
 <div className='  text-lg sm:text-2xl sm:opacity-80 cursor-pointer  text sm:flex sm:justify-evenly grid place-items-center'>
 <Link href="https://e-dnevnik.edu.ba/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" title="">
  <div className=' text-white  circle relative sm:-top-32 mt-5 sm:w-96 sm:h-96 w-64 h-64 rounded-full grid place-items-center'>
  <img className=' opacity-80 sm:h-72  h-48   ' src='/student-cap-svgrepo-com.svg' alt='next' />
  <h1 className='mb-10 opacity-70 '>e-Dnevnik za ucenike</h1>
  </div>
  </Link>

  <Link href="https://e-dnevnik.edu.ba/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" title="">
  <div className=' text-white circle relative sm:-top-32 w-64 max-xl:mt-5 h-64 sm:w-96 sm:h-96 rounded-full grid place-items-center'>
    <img className=' opacity-70 sm:h-72  h-48   ' src="family-silhouette-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="" />
    <h1 className='mb-10 opacity-70 '>e-Dnevnik za ucenike</h1>
  </div>
  </Link>

  <Link href="https://e-dnevnik.edu.ba/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" title="">
  <div  className='text-white circle relative sm:-top-32 w-64 max-xl:mt-5 h-64 sm:w-96 sm:h-96 rounded-full grid place-items-center'>
    <img className=' opacity-70 sm:h-72  h-48   '  src="business-person-silhouette-wearing-tie-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="" />
    <h1 href="https://e-dnevnik.edu.ba/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" className='mb-20 opacity-70 '>e-Dnevnik za ucenike
    </h1>
    
    
  </div>
  </Link>
 </div>
</section>

<section>
{posts.map((post) =>(
  <BlogCard title={post.title} 
  author={post.author} 
  coverPhoto={post.coverPhoto}
   key={post.id} 
  datepublish={post.datepublish} 
  slug={post.slug}/>
))}
</section>
      </main>
     
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't get why is that error occurs, when I'm following online tutorial and checked everything multiple times...

This is BlogCard code:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from '/styles/BlogCard.module.css'

export default function BlogPost({title, author, coverPhoto, datepublish,slug}){
    return(
<div className={styles.card} >
<Link href={'/posts/' + slug}>
<div className={styles.imgContainer}>
    <img src="{coverPhoto.url" alt="" />
</div>
</Link>
</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This line is trying to map over the posts object and render a component for each post. However, it seems that posts is not an array, so it cannot be mapped over.

It's hard to tell from the code snippet you've provided what might be causing this issue, but it could be that the data is not being correctly retrieved from the GraphQL API or the code is not correctly handling the response.

It would be helpful to see the full code of the component that's causing the error.

Comment: You don't show where you **use** `<Home>` or what you're passing to it. That said, `posts` is likely meant to be a prop **given** to the `Home` component, and the parameter to a component is **all** the properties, i.e., you're not destructuring it.

Comment: Tangential: it's best to minimize/remove all unrelated code, styles, etc. The extra noise hides the useful information. It's also best to be explicit about the error--you never actually say what the error **is**.

Answer (score 0):

I just had do add {} to posts in Home. Thanks for replays tho